# Authentication with facebook in Angularfire

Tags: facebook, angularjs, firebase-security

This is my app.js and i am looking to diplay the user id in the URL but it doesnt work.

```
$scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase(FBURL));
 var userID= $scope.auth.user.id;
$scope.comments = $firebase(new Firebase(FBURL+"//users"+userID+"//Cards"));

$scope.addComment = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode != 13) {
    return;
  }
  if ($scope.auth.user === null) {
    alert("You must be logged in to leave a comment");
  } else {
    $scope.comments.$add({
      body: $scope.newComment,
      name: $scope.auth.user.name, id: $scope.auth.user.id
    });
    $scope.newComment = "";
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

}
]);

Anyone can help me in figuring it out , what i am doing wrong there?
Thank you.

Comment: why are double // necessary?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: i tried / as well but doesn't change anything !!

Comment: $firebase(new Firebase(FBURL+"//users"+userID+"//Cards"));
when i remove userID , it works perfectly but when i put userID , it stops working!!

Answer (score 0):

And from where do you take id ? I don`t see somehow facebook login function.

[Edit] I am playing with that just now as i am new to that too. I think you are missing

```
$scope.auth.$login('facebook')
```

This is what is working for me, where from user i am grabbing id, name and so on.

```
//*** FB login
$scope.fbLogin=function(){
    var fbaseRef=new Firebase(FBASE)
    var loginObj=$firebaseSimpleLogin(fbaseRef);

    console.log("Going fbLogin")
    loginObj.$login('facebook').then(function(user){
        console.log("FB Login ok",user)
    },function(rejection){
        console.log("FB Login failes",rejection)
    })
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I didn`t mean to critic. Just playing with facebook login now as i am new to that too. So only wanted be sure i didn`t miss something.

Comment: Updated that now, still not too experienced where to click so my post is in the right place. I am sorry for any inconvenience.